How to track down why an FCM message doesn't appear
I had been using the now deprecated HTTP version of FCM and have switched to the required OAuth version.
The code I use is identical between two of my apps, in one of my apps the message arrives on the device.  On the other app the message does not arrive.
In both cases the Firebase API reports a message ID.  So there's no issue with credentials or tokens (and it's the same code as stated).
So I'm suspecting that some permission or setting within the Firebase console is not the same between the two projects.  Is there a way to use the message ID returned from Firebase to check on its status, to see what happened to it?
I'm talking about the returned string that looks like
projects/xxxproject/messages/1720747275812907

